How to fix lifetime error in the following code?
Here's the code
pub struct List<'a> {
    node: Option<Node<'a>>,
    list_vec: Vec<Node<'a>>,
}


pub struct Node<'a> {
    data: String,
    next: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
}


impl List<'_> {
    fn add(&mut self, val: String, referenced_node: &Node){
        self.node = Some(Node {
            data: String::from(String::from(val)),
            next: Some(referenced_node), // I was expecting to have reference to original variable which i transferred via new_node
        });
}

I was expecting to store reference to original variable as i said in code comment

If you want to store referenced_node, then you need to specify the lifetime of &Node to allow that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This will solve your immediate issue. However, I highly suspect you're trying to create a self-referential struct, a known-to-be-impossible thing.

Associate lifetime 'a with the reference you're putting inside the List<'a>:
// Give lifetime a name here:
//   v        v
impl<'a> List<'a> {
    // And specify that the input reference must have this lifetime:
    //                                               v
    fn add(&mut self, val: String, referenced_node: &'a Node) {
        self.node = Some(Node {
            data: String::from(String::from(val)),
            next: Some(referenced_node), // I was expecting to have reference to original variable which i transferred via new_node
        });
    }
}

